# decltype of variable template functin

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, переменные, аргументы

Я хочу вернуть std::future от возвращаемого значения шаблонной функции с переменным числом аргументов,
но не могу найти как сделать это правильно.

```
        template <typename T, typename ...Args>
        auto add_task(T task, Args ...args)->std::future<decltype(task())>
        {
            auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task()) ()>>(std::move(task));
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(event_mutex);
                tasks.push([=, args...]() { (*wrapper)(args); });
            }
            event.notify_one();
            return wrapper->get_future();
        }
```

И второй вопрос, как правильно вызвать эту функцию?

```
(*wrapper)(args);
(*wrapper)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: decltype(task()) - вряд ли это впринципе будет работать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201835/get-the-type-of-the-return-value-in-c

Comment: По идее, правильно будет заменить `Args ...args` на forwarding-ссылки `Args &&... args`, использовать `decltype(task(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`, и захват лямбды заменить на `[=, ...args = std::forward(args)]` (C++20-онли), ну и вызывать тоже с forward: `(*wrapper)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Думаю это немного не то. В том вопросе автор не знает типы аргументов, а здесь они известны, так что все проще.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ИМХО, сдесь основная загвоздка в возвращаемом значении, и в приведенном ссылке этому тоже уделено основное внимание

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я к тому, что здесь можно просто написать `decltype(task(args...))` (если пренебречь `std::forward`) и все.

Comment: Раз вы захватили переменные по значению `[args....]`, то ничего кроме копирования вам не доступно. Поэтому правильный вариант `(*wrapper)(args...);` forward - выродится в тоже самое.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а это верно подмечено

Comment: Приведите пример вызова этой функции. Что такое tasks? Сейчас написано так, как будто задания не требуют аргументов, к чему тогда args?

Comment: std::function<void(int from, int to)> func;
add_task(func, from, to);

Comment: Ну так а tasks что такое? Приведите [mcve] чтобы не приходилось додумывать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        template <typename F, typename ...Args>
        auto add_task(F&& task, Args&& ...args) ->std::future<decltype(task(args...))>
        {

            auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task(args...))()>>(
                std::bind(std::forward<F>(task), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            );

            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(event_mutex);
                tasks.push([wrapper]() { (*wrapper)(); });
            }

            event.notify_one();
            return wrapper->get_future();
        }
```